# Append path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have been using python3 to set environment variables using `os.environ()`. I was setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a path, which is basically overwriting LD_LIBRARY_PATH using code `os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = PATH`. But I want to add path using separator `:` .

I am trying to add path using string concatenation with separator using `os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] + ":" + PATH` , It doesn't seems to be working like this.

I am getting following error :

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] =os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] + ":" + target_directory
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong or what should be done.

Comment: When you say it doesn't seem to be working do you mean that it returns an error or does it simply not append the PATH. Also can you provide a test PATH that is not working?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

The KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' indicates that such key does not exist in your os.environ dictionary. Thus you cannot append anything to the value of a non-existing key.

You should explicitly set a PATH first, then append if you require to do so. I'd suggest you add a check like `if PATH not in os.environ().keys()` then set  it.

Answer (score 2):

Python lets you easily specify a default value.

```
old = os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
if old:
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = old + ":" + PATH
else:
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = PATH
```

You can accomplish the same with a `try`/`except` but it's not really faster or cleaner than this.

The key here is `dict.get(value)` which unlike `dict[value)` returns `None` instead of raising a `KeyError`. It also allows you to specify a different value than `None` as its second argument.

Comment: You don't need the empty string. The default value is `None` if no default is specified. And, in any case, it's generally better to use `None` for this condition.